# Not able to parse XML in C# with default namespace

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am not able to parse XML document with a default namespace.

If I remove the namespace `xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee` from the XML file, then I am able to get values in nodelist. I don't want to use Linq.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
    <display-name>Test - My tomcat webapp</display-name>
</web-app>
```

C# code:

```
String strFileUsers = @"E:\\Dot_net\\XML_Parser\\demo\\web_org.xml";
XmlDocument docUsers = new XmlDocument();

try
{
    docUsers.Load(strFileUsers);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot open file ");
    return;
}

try
{
    XmlNodeList nodeList = docUsers.SelectNodes("//display-name");

    Console.WriteLine(nodeList.Count);
}   
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an XmlNamespaceManager in your call

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(docUsers.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("test", "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee");  
XmlNodeList nodeList = docUsers.SelectNodes("//test:display-name",ns);
```

Comment: Still getting count null.

Comment: In my case xmlns append after xml tag like <display-name xmlns...>

Comment: Could you please publish sample XML

Comment: Already added in question but I have see this type of behavior in debugging.

Comment: The code works well with sample you published.That is the reason why I asked for another sample as you mentioned  ..<display-name xmlns...>...

Comment: Sorry I am looking wrong file. Now it's working thank you